# Trying to install google apis

Tags: android

I'm trying to install Google apis using sdk manager from eclipse,
but it does not have Google apis in any of the check boxes, in fact it only has 7 items
When I goggled this question, the answer had a picture of Google sdk manager and it had around 30 things you could select
How can I fix this and install the google api lib???

what my SDK manager shows....

Tools:

Android SDK

android sdk platform

api 19:

glass development kit

android 4.22:

sdk platform

arm

Eatras

Android support lib

inte; 866 emulator

Answer (score 0):

Google API was previously used for Maps. Now that is moved to Google Play Services along with other cool features, so there isn't SDK for download - you just have to include play services in your project:
https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html